# Can't read webservice with simplexml_load_string / php

Tags: web-services, simplexml

I'm having some problems while trying to consume a webservice using php.

The first part seems to work fine, when gettin the xml using curl.

But when trying to use simplexml_load_string, I'm getting the following error:

*"Fatal error: Error reading XML string in /home/sites/site1/web/DataDriver/pruebas/dev_lee_ws2.php on line 35"*

Code is written as follows:

```
$sGLN = "7505000010064";
$sUsuario = "DISTRIBU";
$sContrasena = "DISTRIBU";
$sGLNPublicador = "";
$sGTIN = "7500112045058";

$url = "http://demo.syncfonia.com.mx/ws/wsexportaproducto/Productos.asmx/ObtieneProducto?GLN=$sGLN&Usuario=$sUsuario&Contrasena=$sContrasena&GLNPublicador=$sGLNPublicador&GTIN=$sGTIN";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if(!$xmlobj=simplexml_load_string($result)){
    echo "<br>";
    trigger_error('Error reading XML string',E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo 'Displaying email addresses of XML string...<br />';
foreach($xmlobj as $Exportacion){
    echo 'Values of email nodes: '.$Exportacion->refpaismercado.'<br />';
}
```

Also here is the structure of the xml:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/wsexportaproducto/Productos">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Exportacion">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="gtin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="gtinreemplazado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refidcateglobal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refidcatelocal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="gln" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="glnfabricante" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nombrefabricante" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refpaismercado" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="iniciovigenciadn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="finvigenciadn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="vida" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nomproducto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="marca" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="descproducto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="descripcioncorta" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="profundo" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidprofundo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="alto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidalto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ancho" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidancho" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesobruto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesobruto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesoempaque" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesoempaque" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="contenidoneto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidcontenidoneto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="escontenidovariable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refembalaje" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esretornable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="factorestiba" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadminima" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="contenidos" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="refpaisorigen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcolorcodigo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcoloragencia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadcolor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtalleagencia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtallecodigo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtalle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadordenable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cantminimapedir" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="multiplopedir" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esfacturable" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadembarque" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nrocapasartcomercial" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nroartcomercialesporcapa" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidadesporpallet" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidporcapa" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nrodecapas" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="submarca" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadtipo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="oferta" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="dscompania" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nombregen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="variedadsabor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="continentes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="reftiponivel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esunidadconsumo" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pesoneto" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="unidpesoneto" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cantidadtotalcontenida" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="reftipogtin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="esprivado" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="statussecodat" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="accion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="fechaaccion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Exportacion diffgr:id="Exportacion1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<gtin>07500112045058</gtin>
<refidcateglobal>10005730</refidcateglobal>
<gln>7505000010064</gln>
<refpaismercado>484</refpaismercado>
<iniciovigenciadn>2012-08-09T00:00:00-05:00</iniciovigenciadn>
<finvigenciadn>4999-12-31T23:59:59-06:00</finvigenciadn>
<marca>PINTACOLOR</marca>
<descproducto>PINTACOLOR BLANCO</descproducto>
<descripcioncorta>PINTURA PINTACOLOR 18 L</descripcioncorta>
<profundo>40.000000000000000</profundo>
<unidprofundo>CM</unidprofundo>
<alto>60.000000000000000</alto>
<unidalto>CM</unidalto>
<ancho>40.000000000000000</ancho>
<unidancho>CM</unidancho>
<pesobruto>26.200000000000000</pesobruto>
<unidpesobruto>KG</unidpesobruto>
<unidpesoempaque>KG</unidpesoempaque>
<escontenidovariable>false</escontenidovariable>
<esretornable>false</esretornable>
<esunidadminima>true</esunidadminima>
<contenidos/>
<esunidadordenable>false</esunidadordenable>
<esfacturable>true</esfacturable>
<esunidadembarque>false</esunidadembarque>
<oferta>false</oferta>
<dscompania>DISTRIBUIDOR</dscompania>
<nombregen>PINTURA</nombregen>
<continentes/>
<reftiponivel>EA</reftiponivel>
<esunidadconsumo>false</esunidadconsumo>
<esprivado>false</esprivado>
<statussecodat>2</statussecodat>
</Exportacion>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: open http://www.gs1mexico.org/DataDriver/pruebas/dev_lee_ws2.php and right-click  and select "view source"

Comment: When I do that, I can see the XML returned by webservice, as far as I can see it is correct. Still getting the error

Comment: the code you posted contains only 24 lines - so something here doesn't make any sense (since the error is triggered on line 35)

Comment: You are right, Im sorry, I didnt post some commented lines. The line 35 of the code is: trigger_error('Error reading XML string',E_USER_ERROR);

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first 8 lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
```

from the `$result` string

Comment: I see now, the content type is `text/html` - it should be `text/xml`. add the following line to dev_lee_ws2.php: `header('Content-type: text/xml');`

Comment: Thank you alfasin, when I put that, at the end I get the xml shown on screen. But still get the error. Im not looking to show the entire xml, Im looking to get some data of the xml, thats why Im trying to use simplexml_load_string

Comment: What you have there is a mishmash of XML and XSD. Since it's not a valid XML - it cannot be parsed into a constructed object.

Comment: I understand, do you any other way to achieve my goal? thanks in advance.

Comment: you should provide a valid XML in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by replacing all attributes with colon `:` in his name, like `diffgr:id` and etc, before parsing with `simplexml_load_string()`;